# how can bind gridview to array

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, data-binding, string

I want to bind 2d array to gridview. How can do so. I am attaching my code also. If there is any other way then also suggest me.

```
        string sQS;
        string[] aQS;
        string pwd = "ebskey";
        string DR = Request.QueryString["DR"].ToString();
        DR = DR.Replace(' ', '+');
        sQS = Base64Decode(DR);
        DR = EBSHelper.Decrypt(pwd, sQS, false);
        aQS = DR.Split('&');
        int p1 = aQS.Length;
        string[,] pp = new string[p1,2];
        for (int i = 0; i < aQS.Length; i++)
        {
            string[] aParam = aQS[i].Split('=');
            pp[i,0] = aParam[0].ToString();
            pp[i,1] = aParam[1].ToString();

        }
        GridView1.DataSource = pp;
        GridView1.DataBind();
```

Answer (score 2):

As I understand your input string is like this:

```
var inputString = "key1=value1&key2=value2&key3=value3";
```

The code below will parse the string and make a list, and bind it to a grid.

```
var list = Regex.Matches(inputString, @"(?<key>\w+)=(?<value>\w+)(&|$)")
    .Cast<Match>()
    .Select(arg => new { Key = arg.Groups["key"].Value, Value = arg.Groups["value"].Value })
    .ToList();
GridView1.DataSource = list;
GridView1.DataBind();
```

So your final code would look like this:

```
string pwd = "ebskey";
string DR = Request.QueryString["DR"];
DR = DR.Replace(' ', '+');
string sQS = Base64Decode(DR);
DR = EBSHelper.Decrypt(pwd, sQS, false);

var list = Regex.Matches(DR, @"(?<key>\w+)=(?<value>\w+)(&|$)")
    .Cast<Match>()
    .Select(arg => new { Key = arg.Groups["key"].Value, Value = arg.Groups["value"].Value })
    .ToList();
GridView1.DataSource = list;
GridView1.DataBind();
```

Answer (score 2):

I would try something like this instead of a 2d array.

```
var data = aQS.Select(s => new {Col1 = s.Split('=')[0], Col2 = s.Split('=')[1]});
GridView1.DataSource = data;
GridView1.DataBind();
```

I don't like calling `Split()` twice but I'm not sure how to work around that.

or you can keep things really straighforward and create a simple class

```
class RowData{
    public string Col1Value {get; set;}
    public string Col2Value {get; set;}
}
```

and you can do

```
List<RowData> rows = new List<RowData>();
for (int i = 0; i < aQS.Length; i++)
 {
        string[] aParam = aQS[i].Split('=');
        RowData row = new RowData {Col1Data = aParam[0], Col2Data = aParam[1]};
        rows.Add(row);
 }

 GridView1.DataSource = rows;
 GridView1.DataBind();
```

Comment: The workaround to 'calling it twice' is 'calling it once' :).

Comment: @Alex Feel free to edit the answer if you can come up with a way to skip the second redundant call.

Comment: I think it is better not to make `aQS` array in the first place.

Comment: In your first version, you could do this to avoid double splits:             var data =
                from s in aQS
                let split = s.Split('=')
                select new { Col1 = split[0], Col2 = split[1] };