# How to populate GridView with two string values

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

```
<asp:GridView ID="gvData" EmptyDataText="No data to display" ClientIDMode="Static" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false" CssClass="gvData">
    <Columns>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Content">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="lblID" runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static" Text='<%# Eval("Provider") %>'></asp:Label>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="In Collection(s)">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="lblID" runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static" Text='<%# Eval("Collection") %>'></asp:Label>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

C#:

```
strCollFinalized = ddlContent.SelectedValue + "," + CheckInCollection(Convert.ToInt64(ddlContent.SelectedItem.Value)); //returns two string values
string[] strL = strCollFinalized.Split(',');
gvData.DataSource = strL;
gvData.DataBind();
```

The above code gives me an error:

```
DataBinding: 'System.String' does not contain a property with the name 'Provider'.
```

How can I populate the first string into `Provider` column and the second string into `Collection` column.

Comment: do you have the datagrid `Auto Generate Columns` set to false..?

Comment: try to bind the columns to Container.DataItem instead - Text=<%# Container.DataItem %>

Comment: Yes it is currently set to `false`

Comment: you need to name the split items to the same value as the data in your Eval

Comment: @codeRecap Will it know it is two separate column in the order I use it?

Comment: I would change using a string array and use a Class to represent the names of the columns you're trying to bind.. also look at this example for further clarification http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6380449/how-can-bind-gridview-to-array

Comment: It should! (would be strange if it didn't)

Comment: @codeRecap it does populate :) except one value is for both column and next value is for both columns too. I don't know if it makes sense on what I said. I want the first value for the first column and second value for the second column.

Comment: ah, now I see. it will populate two rows, of course. if you want to see two columns with distinct values, as one possible (and simplest) solution, you'll have to create an object with two properties, each assigned to items in your array respectively, and then bind the columns to the properties

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are getting that error cause of your `Templatefield` specifically when you say `Text='<%# Eval("Provider") %>`. So it's looking for a property/column name `Provider` in the source which is not present and so the error.

If you want to make this string collection as source for gridview then remove those templatefield altogether and then probably you can say

```
List<string> strL = strCollFinalized.Split(',').ToList();
gvData.DataSource = strL;
gvData.DataBind();
```

Another way would be creating a `DataTable` like

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
DataColumn dc = new Datacolumn("Provider");
DataColumn dc1 = new Datacolumn("Collection");

dt.columns.Add(dc);
dt.columns.Add(dc1);

DataRow dr = dt.NewRow();
dr[dc] = ddlContent.SelectedValue;
dr[dc1] = CheckInCollection(Convert.ToInt64(ddlContent.SelectedItem.Value));

dt.Rows.Add(dr);
gvData.DataSource = dt;
gvData.DataBind();
```

Comment: It does work except the first value is shown for both columns and the second value is shown for both columns

Comment: @SiKni8, Do a quick look into the edit I just made. will work for you.

Comment: Then I will have to set the auto generate column to true. right?

Comment: Ahh!!! Yes you will have to. Now it will work even if you don't have those templatefield.

Comment: How can I fix the string split? It is not displaying correctly. I have the lines as this: `strCollFinalized = "" + ddlContent.SelectedItem + "," + CheckInCollection(Convert.ToInt64(ddlContent.SelectedItem.Value)) + "";
   List<string> strL = strCollFinalized.Split(',').ToList();`

Comment: didn't got you. you mean your split is not working? No need of converting it to list. Keep your code only since now we are making a datatable.

Comment: The only issue is my first column also has a `,` so it never gets the third item in the list :/ I will use a `|` character to be safe. I am trying this now.

Comment: @SiKni8, you don't need to split probably. see edit again. You can just assign the values directly.

Comment: The only issue I have is the `CheckCollection` function returns a string which is in a forloop like this: `strColl += item.Id.ToString() + " (" + item.Title + ")" + "\r\n";` but the column is not displaying each string in a new line.

Comment: @SiKni8, that's interesting. Consider posting it as separate question. You can link this question if you want for reference but it's a separate question altogether.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34642308/how-to-show-new-line-in-a-gridview-column

Comment: @SiKni8, in that case consider accepting this question since your main issue per this post have been worked out.