# How to show new line in a GridView column

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I have the following C# function:

```
public string CheckInCollection(long lngProvId)
{
    //...
    foreach (var item in collList)
    {
        strColl += item.Id.ToString() + " (" + item.Title + ")" + "\r\n";
    }

    return strColl;
}
```

The following C# function:

```
public void PopulateGridView(bool blType)
{
    if (blType == false)
    {
    }
    else
    {
        strCollFinalized = "" + ddlContent.SelectedItem + "|" + CheckInCollection(Convert.ToInt64(ddlContent.SelectedItem.Value)) + "";
        string[] strL = strCollFinalized.Split('|');

        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        DataColumn dc = new DataColumn("Provider");
        DataColumn dc1 = new DataColumn("Collection");

        dt.Columns.Add(dc);
        dt.Columns.Add(dc1);

        DataRow dr = dt.NewRow();
        dr[dc] = strL[0];
        dr[dc1] = strL[1];

        dt.Rows.Add(dr);
        gvData.DataSource = dt;
        gvData.DataBind();
    }
}
```

When the gridview is generated the second column is displayed in one line but when I check the source, it is displaying in the next line.

How can I modify so that the returned string shows each `strColl` in a new line.

Comment: try adding "<br/>" instead of "\r\n"

Comment: Then the column shows the `<br />` instead of translating into Html.

Comment: Take a look at this: http://codeverge.com/asp.net.presentation-controls/make-gridview-column-multiline/476148

Comment: try adding a Literal or Label control and add text to it

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As @user2169261 suggested, you can add `<br>` instead of `\r\n`

Then you can set the `HtmlEncode` property of the column you want to show the newline to `false`.

For example:

```
<Columns>
    <asp:BoundField DataField="Whatever" HtmlEncode="False" />
</Columns>
```

For autogenerated columns, you can try following approach (as per this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2168663/2177143))

Make your own inspection of the DataTable and create an explicit BoundColumn for each column:

```
foreach (DataColumn column in dt.Columns)
{
    GridViewColumn boundColumn = new BoundColumn
    {
        DataSource = column.ColumnName,
        HeaderText = column.ColumnName,
        HtmlEncode = false
    };
    gvData.Columns.Add(boundColumn);
}

gvData.DataSource = dt;
gvData.DataBind();
```

Comment: I am auto generating the columns so that won't work unfortunately :/

Comment: I just noticed that, I am searching if I can set the encoding to false programatically

Comment: I see what you are doing... Setting the boundfield settings before assigning to gridview. I will test it out. Thanks.

Comment: I had to manipulate and add it in the `RowDataBound` function. Thank you for the help.